# Android Workmanager

Tags: android, workmanagers, lifecycleowner

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use Android's Workmanager. Essentially, I want to make a OneTime request with a time delay, determine success, then do some stuff. The Worker class does NOTHING.

What I'm expecting is a SUCCESS code to be returned after the time delay. That is, the sole purpose of my Workmanager code is to provide a delay.

I know there are many other ways to effect a delay but my understanding is that Android "protects" Workmanager Workers better than, say, AlarmManager.

Unfortunately, I can't make it happen.

Here's what I've done

1. Extended my activity to include LifecycleOwner
2. Added the required getLifeCycle method, as below

   ```
   @NonNull
   @Override
   public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
       Log.d (TAG, "getLifecycle(): " + getLifecycle());
       return getLifecycle();
   }
   ```
3. Here's the Worker class

   ```
   public class makeAlarm extends Worker {

       public makeAlarm(
           @NonNull Context context,
           @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
           super(context, params);
       }

       @Override
       public Result doWork() {
           // Do the work here--in this case, do nothing

           // Indicate whether the task finished successfully with the Result
           return Result.success();
      }
   }
   ```
4. And here's my action code

   ```
   // Create a OneTimeWorkRequest that delays "success" by the required time
   OneTimeWorkRequest makeAlarmWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(makeAlarm.class)
           .setInitialDelay(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .build();
   WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(makeAlarmWorkRequest);

   // The following stmt. shows what appears to be a valid id
   Log.d (TAG, "makeAlarmWorkRequest.getId(): " + makeAlarmWorkRequest.getId());

   WorkManager.getInstance(this).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(makeAlarmWorkRequest.getId())
           .observe(myLifecycleOwner, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
               @Override
               public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkInfo workInfo) {
                   if (workInfo != null && workInfo.getState() == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {

                   // Some amazing work here...

                   }
               }
           });
   ```

I've tried a number of variations but haven't had success. 
The above code results in a stack overflow crash.
Help!

Comment: The success code is returned from the class in which doWork() is defined. You need to share the code of that class too.

Comment: Sorry, Divya, not sure I understand. Isn't it already being shared? [I've added the Worker class for your reference]

Comment: Update the library version of Work Manager to latest one and see if it's working. Your code seems fine.